# Android: Not able to access getter method from POJO class

Tags: android, arraylist, adapter, baseadapter, pojo

I am using adapter inside my activity to set values of my listview. For that I am passing one Arraylist of POJO class to adapter. But when I am trying to set text in textview of my listview, that time I am not able to access getName getter method.

PurchaseActivity:

```
package eukti.myafterclass.ui;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import eukti.myafterclass.R;
import eukti.myafterclass.adapter.PurchaseBaseAdapter;
import eukti.myafterclass.controller.CallRestApi;
import eukti.myafterclass.dto.PurchasePojo;
import eukti.myafterclass.utils.Constants;

public class PurchaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView purchaseListView;
    private ArrayList<PurchasePojo> arrayList;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private SharedPreferences afterClassPref;
    private String university_uuid;
    private PurchaseBaseAdapter purchaseBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase);
        purchaseListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.purchaseListView);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<PurchasePojo>();
        afterClassPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        university_uuid = afterClassPref.getString("studentUniversityUUID", null);
    }

    private void getNotesSubjectList(final boolean isShared){
        PurchaseActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PurchaseActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.setMessage("please wait, fetching data... ");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        });
        Map<String,String> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
        paramMap.put("university_uuid", university_uuid);
        paramMap.put(Constants.UC_KEY, "scheme");
        paramMap.put(Constants.MODULE_KEY, "student");
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams(paramMap);
        Log.d("Purchase Packages ", "params: " + params);
        CallRestApi.get(Constants.BASE_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("Purchase Packages ", " Response :" + response);

                if (response != null) {
                    try {

                        if (response.getBoolean("status")) {
                            JSONArray resultArray = response.optJSONArray("result");
                            if (resultArray != null) {
                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                arrayList = gson.fromJson(resultArray.getJSONObject(0).toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<PurchasePojo>>(){}.getType());
                                purchaseBaseAdapter = new PurchaseBaseAdapter(PurchaseActivity.this, arrayList);
                            }


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (progressDialog != null) {
                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PurchasePojo:

```
package eukti.myafterclass.dto;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class PurchasePojo {

    @SerializedName("uuid")
    @Expose
    private String uuid;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("ask_question")
    @Expose
    private String askQuestion;
    @SerializedName("view_expert_answer")
    @Expose
    private String viewExpertAnswer;
    @SerializedName("question_bank")
    @Expose
    private String questionBank;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;
    @SerializedName("is_default")
    @Expose
    private String isDefault;
    @SerializedName("enabled")
    @Expose
    private String enabled;
    @SerializedName("created")
    @Expose
    private String created;
    @SerializedName("created_by")
    @Expose
    private String createdBy;
    @SerializedName("modified")
    @Expose
    private String modified;
    @SerializedName("modified_by")
    @Expose
    private String modifiedBy;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The uuid
     */
    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param uuid
     * The uuid
     */
    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * The name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The askQuestion
     */
    public String getAskQuestion() {
        return askQuestion;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param askQuestion
     * The ask_question
     */
    public void setAskQuestion(String askQuestion) {
        this.askQuestion = askQuestion;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The viewExpertAnswer
     */
    public String getViewExpertAnswer() {
        return viewExpertAnswer;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param viewExpertAnswer
     * The view_expert_answer
     */
    public void setViewExpertAnswer(String viewExpertAnswer) {
        this.viewExpertAnswer = viewExpertAnswer;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The questionBank
     */
    public String getQuestionBank() {
        return questionBank;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param questionBank
     * The question_bank
     */
    public void setQuestionBank(String questionBank) {
        this.questionBank = questionBank;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The price
     */
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param price
     * The price
     */
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The isDefault
     */
    public String getIsDefault() {
        return isDefault;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param isDefault
     * The is_default
     */
    public void setIsDefault(String isDefault) {
        this.isDefault = isDefault;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The enabled
     */
    public String getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param enabled
     * The enabled
     */
    public void setEnabled(String enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The created
     */
    public String getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param created
     * The created
     */
    public void setCreated(String created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The createdBy
     */
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param createdBy
     * The created_by
     */
    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The modified
     */
    public String getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param modified
     * The modified
     */
    public void setModified(String modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The modifiedBy
     */
    public String getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param modifiedBy
     * The modified_by
     */
    public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

}
```

PurchaseBaseAdapter:

```
package eukti.myafterclass.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import eukti.myafterclass.R;
import eukti.myafterclass.dto.PurchasePojo;

/**
 * Created by cuser on 11/1/16.
 */
public class PurchaseBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<PurchasePojo> arrayList;
    private TextView price, name, pqTextView, vaTextView;

    public PurchaseBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PurchasePojo> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.account_list_items, null);
            }
            name        = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            price       = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            pqTextView  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pqTextView);
            vaTextView  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vaTextView);

            name.setText(arrayList.getName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

name.setText(arrayList.getName()); this line in adapter is showing error because of getName().

Comment: Well, what error is it showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your getName() with get(position).getName().
And your getView method will look like this,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.account_list_items, null);
        }
        name        = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        price       = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        pqTextView  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pqTextView);
        vaTextView  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vaTextView);

        name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Soooo, essentially the same answer as I posted 2 hours ago. Very useful answer indeed...Not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access that list's element first. Replace

```
name.setText(arrayList.getName());
```

by

```
name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
```